# Derive stdio FILE handle from ostream (stdout)

Tags: c++, ostream

I am using cout/ostream in a c++ project.  But it relies on a C project that uses stdio (FILE).

So I want to write a function like

```
void MyLog(ostream output) {
   OLD_UGLY_C_FUNCTION(ostream.toStdio());
}
```

Is that possible?  In pre C++11?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: "Given a C++ stream, there is no general way to find out its file descriptor." look [here](http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/)

Comment: @Kellerspeicher You should write that (with a bit more detail) as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is the system and compiler dependants. You need a lot of effort to be portable. In the question there is no OS and no compiler given. To find a good solution read the chapter "A Solution" in [this](http://www.ginac.de/~kreckel/fileno/#ASolution) document. There is code to cut and paste. It makes no sense to copy here. And take care about the difference of "file handle" or " `FILE*` stream" and "file descriptor". The first relies on the second. This is also very good described in the cited document.

Comment: Nice article referenced, thanks.  But I think the basic answer is just NO, not possible.  I obviously should be.